# what's the difference between a method referenced by an asterisk and method that isn't in Golang?

Tags: go, oop, pointers, methods, struct

Let's suppose I have a struct, and this struct has 2 methods. one is written with an asterisk and the other one isn't.
Here is the code to understand the example.

```golang
type object struct{
    name string
    age int
}

func (obj *object) methodOne{
    // do something
} 
func (obj object) methodTwo{
    // do something
}
```

I know about pointers, but still didn't understand the concept in this example.

Comment: https://go.dev/tour/methods/4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As docs says:](https://go.dev/doc/faq#Pointers)

```
func (s *MyStruct) pointerMethod() { } // method on pointer
func (s MyStruct)  valueMethod()   { } // method on value
```

> For programmers unaccustomed to pointers, the distinction between
> these two examples can be confusing, but the situation is actually
> very simple. When defining a method on a type, the receiver (s in the
> above examples) behaves exactly as if it were an argument to the
> method. Whether to define the receiver as a value or as a pointer is
> the same question, then, as whether a function argument should be a
> value or a pointer. There are several considerations.
>
> First, and most important, does the method need to modify the
> receiver? If it does, the receiver must be a pointer. (Slices and maps
> act as references, so their story is a little more subtle, but for
> instance to change the length of a slice in a method the receiver must
> still be a pointer.) In the examples above, if pointerMethod modifies
> the fields of s, the caller will see those changes, but valueMethod is
> called with a copy of the caller's argument (that's the definition of
> passing a value), so changes it makes will be invisible to the caller.
>
> Second is the consideration of efficiency. If the receiver is large, a
> big struct for instance, it will be much cheaper to use a pointer
> receiver.
>
> Next is consistency. If some of the methods of the type must have
> pointer receivers, the rest should too, so the method set is
> consistent regardless of how the type is used. See the section on
> method sets for details.
>
> For types such as basic types, slices, and small structs, a value
> receiver is very cheap so unless the semantics of the method requires
> a pointer, a value receiver is efficient and clear.